# How can I make a carousel slider that uses dots for pagination instead of arrows

Tags: jquery

I need to create a div carousel for a project Im working on. I need multiple divs showing in the frame instead of the standard singular so it will look a bit like this http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html but I need it to use dots for pagination like this http://slidesjs.com/ instead of arrows.

How can I make this or are there any plugins already out?

Comment: Kind of like this? http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html You just have to change the CSS.

Comment: haha yeah thanks, carn't believe I missed that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the jquery tools library which is quite light.

Here is a quick example for what you want : http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/edit.html

I hope it helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Link is down. But I've found it on the [Waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119132605/http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/edit.html) archive